# Convert linked images to embedded

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I have lots of Word files that contain linked images. These Word files are created automatically on a network drive, in a temporary folder that has to be emptied regularly.

So I have to move the Word file to a different folder for archiving. 
When I move the Word file, the images keep pointing to the temporary folder. When I delete the temporary folder, the moved Word file no longer has working images.

There are 2 ways to solve this problem:

- Convert the linked images to embedded images.
- Change the path of the linked image to the archive folder.

I know I can do this manually via File->Edit links to files, but I'd prefer to do this via a macro. This macro does both: first it changes the path to the archive folder, then it breaks the link:

```
Sub ConvertLinkedImagesToEmbedded()
Dim i As Integer
Dim OldName As String
Dim OldPath As String
Dim NewPath As String
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
        ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(i).Select
        If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(i).Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture Then
            OldName = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(i).LinkFormat.SourceName
            OldPath = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(i).LinkFormat.SourcePath
            NewPath = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & OldName
            Dim Ext As String
                If FileThere(NewPath) Then
                  Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=NewPath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                  ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(i).LinkFormat.Update
                Else
                MsgBox "ConvertLinkedImagesToEmbedded: image file " & NewName & " does not exist.", vbOKOnly
                End If
            End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function FileThere(FileName As String) As Boolean
    FileThere = (Dir(FileName) > "")
End Function
```

This looks like it should work: when I run it, the type of each image is changed from wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture to wdInlineShapePicture. 
The file size also changes, indicating that the images have been embedded in the file. When I delete the temporary folder, the Word file still shows the images.

But when I go to File->Edit links to files, all images are still listed as linked images. Worse, the links still point to the temporary folder. So if someone ever uses this dialog box to update one of the files, he'll lose the image.

So the question is, how can I get the File->Edit links to files dialog to display the correct state of the images (i.e. embedded)?

Comment: Just looking at your code (i.e. I haven't actually tried running it, and may not have time to look further for a couple of weeks), I would guess that you are successfully adding *an additional unlinked picture* in your Selection.InlineShapes line but then attempting to updatethe existing link. The Selection line may be OK but maybe you need then to delete the existing InlineShape (and you may need to adjust your loop as the index of the next inlineshape may change as a result).

Comment: @Hobbes: Are you able to solve the above issue?

Comment: I'll have to check how I handled this, but have no access to the project at the moment. Will check in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the original post while looking for a way to unlink linked pictures; here's what I ended up with. I'm having it add a border to the pictures to verify that it's done something; easily commented out if not desired.

```
Sub BreakPictureLinks()

Dim intCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveDocument

'loop through inline shapes
For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count

    With .InlineShapes(i)
        'check if the current shape is a linked picture
        If .Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture Then

            ' Give it a border
           .Line.BackColor = vbBlack
           .Line.Weight = 1
           .Line.Style = msoLineSingle

            ' unlink it
            '.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True
            .LinkFormat.BreakLink

        End If
    End With

Next i

End With    ' Active document

End Sub
```